# d3.js How to draw a directed graph with one node start and one node end

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, directed-graph

Anyone knows d3.js? I have a question:

*Is it possible that I draw a directed graph?*

Note that：the graph starts at one node and may ends with one node.So it's not a tree.

Example:
  A->B->C,A->D->C. those are paths in one graph.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853485/d3-js-collapsible-tree-how-to-connect-different-parents-with-same-child) You'll find all explanations and options for your problem there.

Comment: @skymoney, is it possible to review my answer an to mark it if it was useful? :)